# Best way to retrieve huge around 100k data for auto complete

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have list of addresses for one state. It is near to 100k records. Now when user type something in textbox on website than it will auto complete by above list. Currently I am using store data into xml and make chache for it. Is it best way or I have to create table for it and create view or sp for to retrieve data ? if tables is best way than how I have to design it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100k is really not that large. A flat file should be fine since you really just need to store this information in memory so you can load it up later. The whole benefit of using a relational model is so that you can filter through large quantities of data quickly, but 100k is really easy enough to just sort in memory.

Comment: Flat file is about as close to "pedal-to-the-metal" for these scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting index on that column? With indexes, retrieving data will be very fast, especially if addresses are not changed frequently.